# rails development ssl and http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ssl

I've got an app that calls another servers for authenticating users but it returns verification via https; what's the easiest way to set up a development environment so that my app can react to either 80 or 443 responses?  I'm already using a port mapper to route 80 requests to 3000, but unsure what to do with the 443 request?

Answer (score 0):

I recommed to you PRAX, this tool is a proxy for simpler local development, it supports SSL.

https://github.com/ysbaddaden/prax

Comment: Appreciate it but I'm on OSX: Mac OS X -- Mac OS X isn't supported yet.

Comment: Ah - but POW is definitely something I can use - however unsure how that's going to help yet with the ssl response...